# Tagging user in post, facebook PHP SDK, issues

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

im posting to a users wall, i have the id and everything else, but i cannot seem to "tag" friends, here is the code (I followed their documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts):

```
$tags = $tag1 . $tag2 . ',someID';
// tag 1 and tag 2 are also IDs of users, seperated by a comma only, no whitespace
$place = '110343502319180';


        $attachment = array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'message' => $message,
            'link' => $link,
            'name' => $title,
            'description' => $desc,
            'picture'=>$pic,
            'place'=>$place,
            'tags'=>$tags,
            'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
        );

        $post_url = '/' . $row['uid'].'/feed';
        $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $attachment );
```

I specify a place, and 3 user IDs, to tag, it does not work.

For info, the story does get posted, but the tag and the location are not defined in it..

Comment: Shouldn't it be : `$tags = $tag1 . ',' . $tag2 . ',someID';`

Comment: well, $tag1 = 'id' . ','; 

So no :)

Comment: May be `$tags = $tag1 . ',' . $tag2 . ',' . ',someID';`

Comment: let me clear this up, i add the , after the tags, when i echo $tags, i get

id,id,id

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#creating tells: Capabilities are additional API features for actions; they are optional but enabling them requires additional review during the approval process before they can be used by people who aren't developers or testers of the app (see Guidelines for Action Capabilities). Capabilities are place and tags.